# How to check if two objects inherit from the same base class?

Tags: .net, inheritance, c++-cli, overriding, overloading

I'm trying to override Object::Equals in C++ .NET but I'm running into some difficulties

```
virtual bool IState::Equals(Object^ o) override{
        if (o->GetType() == IState::typeid){
            IState^ s = (IState^) o;
            if (s->type == this->type &&
                s->target_state == this->target_state &&
                s->current_state == this->current_state){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This code works fine if o is and IState. However, I inherit from IState with State. I'd like my Equals function to return true if I pass a State with the same content.

I get that State is not the same as IState, but is there an operator which will allow me to check if they inherit from the same base class?
Maybe overloading the operator typeid *might* help, but it seems like a lot of trouble for that

Comment: For what it's worth, you're violating .NET guidelines by having a class whose name is prefixed with I (which suggests it's an interface).

Comment: changed the tag since C++/CLI and C++ are very different beasts. :)

Comment: Why are you overriding anything in an Interface?  Interfaces shouldn't have implementation.

Comment: well I'm currently testing stuff so it was first an interface then it got an implementation. Besides naming convention, I'm sure there is some way to make it work!

Comment: I didn't mean to start a holy war here, just wanted to point it out. I'd try to help with your problem, but I have no idea how to do the "is" or "as" operators in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is using reflection an option?  If so, take a look at the [Type::IsAssignableFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) method, and the [Type::BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) property.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this is to use dynamic_cast, and check for nullptr:

```
virtual bool IState::Equals(Object^ o) override {
    IState^ s = dynamic_cast<IState^>(o);
    if (s != nullptr) {
        ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

C-style cast (avoid those BTW) that you have used will actually do a safe_cast, which throws InvalidCastException on failure, so you have to spell out dynamic_cast explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to get it to work

I was missing the ->BaseType() after the ->GetType()

here is the working version

```
virtual bool IState::Equals(Object^ o) override{
        if (o->GetType()->BaseType() == IState::typeid){
                IState^ s = (IState^) o;
                if (s->type == this->type &&
                        s->target_state == this->target_state &&
                        s->current_state == this->current_state){
                        return true;
                }
                else{
                        return false;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

thank you all for your time, support and devotion =)

Comment: This will still break if you add one more inheritance level; i.e. IState <- Foo <- Bar, and then pass an instance of Bar to your IState::Equals().

Answer (score 0):

How about using the typeid operator?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec(VS.80).aspx

Comment: This is basically what I do. If I use the typeid() then the compiler tells me to use the ::typeid syntax with error c3185
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf08zfcc.aspx